# ButtonGroup with mutliplechoices

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-elements

i am new to `react-hooks` and `react-native` along with `react-native elements`.
What i am trying here is to be able to choose multiple buttons at once, but i am only able to choose one at a time. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as i am following the instructions on:
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/button_group/

this is my current code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {ButtonGroup} from 'react-native-elements';

const WeekdaySelector = React.memo(props => {
const buttons = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
const [selectedIndexes, setSelectedIndexes] = useState([]);

return(
    <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <ButtonGroup
        onPress={index =>
            setSelectedIndexes(prevState => [...prevState, parseInt(index)])
        }
        buttons={buttons}
        selectMultiple={true}
        selectedIndexes={selectedIndexes}
        />
    </View>
);

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
viewContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}
});

export default WeekdaySelector
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to save and change previous values. The `index` values already taken over are in array.

```js
return(
    <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <ButtonGroup
        onPress={index =>
            setSelectedIndexes(index)
        }
        buttons={buttons}
        selectMultiple={true}
        selectedIndexes={selectedIndexes}
        />
    </View>
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `selectMultiple` prop to true

```
<ButtonGroup
        buttons={['Multiple', 'Select', 'Button', 'Group']}
        selectMultiple
        selectedIndexes={selectedIndexes}
        onPress={(value) => {
          setSelectedIndexes(value);
        }}
        containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
      />
```